# Give an example of a set that is closed under a norm and not closed under another

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

**Q:** Give an example of a vector space $E$ and a subset $F$ of $E$ such that $F$ is closed under a norm topology and not closed under another norm topology.

I tried to find an example but i was not able to come up with one. I only now that $E$ can not be a vector space with finite dimension, because then any two norms are equivalent.

I imagine that a good example can be found in $C([a,b], \mathbb{R^n})$, but i wasn't able to find it. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that space, the set of functions $f$ such that $f(a)=0$ is closed with respect to $\|f\|_{\text{sup}}=\sup|f|$, but it is not closed with respect to the norm $\|f\|_{\text{int}}=\int_a^b|f|$. Can you justify it?

Comment: I was able to prove its closed with respect to the sup norm, but i can't prove it is not closed in the integral norm. Any hints?

Comment: Define$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n(x-a)&\text{ if }x\in\left[a,a+\frac1n\right]\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Each $f_n$ belongs to that set, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=1$, which does *not* belong to it.

Comment: Thank you José, now i managed to prove everything. Cumpliments from Brazil!